# Couldn't get the total amount of each row

Tags: php, mysql

I was having difficulty trying to get the total amount of each row with this code:

```
Total Sales for this day:
    <b>Php <?php

function formatMoney ($number, $fractional=false) {

  if ($fractional) {
    $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
  }

  while (true) {
    $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
    if ($replaced != $number) {
      $number = $replaced;
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return $number;

} // formatMoney

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(sales) FROM sales where date='$startDate'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $rrr=$row['sum(sales)'];
  echo formatMoney($rrr, true);
}

?>
```

But once I manually inserted the data straight to the database it appears to be working. It’s just that whenever I tried to add a data through the system, the values isn't showing at all.

Apart from it, I’m also having issue with how to refresh a column if the one next to it has placed a value that is connected to it.

Any idea? I’m getting stuck with this one.

**Additional Information:**

Here's the actual table.

```
No. of Remaining Property  No. of Rented Property  Rent Cost  Amt. Tendered
           1                            1              1000         1000 
           1                                           1200
```

If there's a value placed in `No. of Rented Property` [example 1], the other column beside it `No. of Remaining Property`, must be refreshed and should display 0. Then the value for the Amount tendered must be=No. of Rented Property x Rent Cost.

You see the first row has values in it. And its working since I do a manual insert on the database. But The second row shows only the value for `No. of Remaining Property` and the rest is empty. When I tried to add value in `NoRentedProperty` the `NoOfRemaningProperty` still displays 1 and the amount was not being multiplied to the Amount Tendered.

I’ve checked my code and am quite sure that it’s all fine. But I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: is your date is FULL date as in MM DD YY with HH MM SS ?

Comment: don't use `mysql_`, use either `mysqli_` or PDO.  Also, where's your insert statements? How are you adding data "through the system"?

Comment: Or can you please post your sample data from table?

Comment: @user2767299 yes my date was YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @cale_b my insert statement was linked to another .php file. Here's the code

`$proname=$_POST['proname'];`
`$tenant=$_POST['tenant'];`
`$location=$_POST['location'];`
`$price=$_POST['price'];`
`$pqty=$_POST['pqty'];`
`$qtysold=$_POST['qtysold'];`
`$date=$_POST['startDate'];`
`mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable` `(item,details,location,qtyleft,qtysold,price,startDate) VALUES` `('$proname','$tenant','$location','$pqty','$qtysold','$price','$date')");`

Comment: I was about to paste here the other codes and add another details to explain things but the commentbox couldn't accept it coz its too long, and when I tried to add it on my post above, it keeps on having error saying I need to indent my post 4 times etc...

Answer (score 0):

First & foremost, you should always format your code to make it easier to read. It helps you debug issues like this better & it helps others—like us—aid you in debugging issues:

```
function formatMoney ($number, $fractional=false) {

  if ($fractional) {
    $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
  }

  while (true) {
    $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
    if ($replaced != $number) {
      $number = $replaced;
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return $number;

} // formatMoney

$query_sql = "SELECT SUM(sales) sales_total FROM sales WHERE date='$startDate'";
// echo $query_sql . '<br />';


$result1 = mysql_query($query_sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $rrr = $row['sales_total'];
  echo formatMoney($rrr, true);
}
```

The main thing I did beyond basic formatting is to return `SUM(sales)` as `sales_total`.

As far as formatting goes, I also set the actual query SQL in a variable named `$query_sql` and have a commented out line with `echo $query_sql . '<br />';` in it. I recommend you uncomment that on your system and look at the query that is being set & test that directly in the database itself.

Given the fact you are not providing examples of what `$startDate` looks like—or explaining where that comes from—not much else can be done to debug this.